# Pytorch cpu-only build from source failing with caffe2 on

Tags: build, pytorch, openmp, caffe2

I was trying to build caffe2 within Pytorch directory but couldn't find a way to build it. The build seems to fail always. Can somebody tell what & how to do?

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch
cd pytorch
git checkout tags/v2.0.1
export USE_CAFFE2=1
export USE_CUDA=0
export USE_MKLDNN=1
export BUILD_CAFFE2_OPS=1
export BUILD_CAFFE2=1
export USE_OPENMP=1
export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=${CONDA_PREFIX:-"$(dirname $(which conda))/../"}
export _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1
BUILD_CAFFE2=ON BUILD_CAFFE2_OPS=ON USE_MKLDNN=ON python setup.py install
```

Comment: Build summary attached